# Creating Max and Min list for Rolling Sublists

Tags: python, list, sublist, rolling-computation

I have a list that contains sublists:

```
[{'h': '20', 'l': '9'}, {'h': '30', 'l': '20'}, {'h': '25', 'l': '7'}, {'h': '18', 'l': '19'}, {'h': '22', 'l': '3'}]
```

I wish to work my way from left to right, finding the max for 'h' and the min for 'l' within the decreasing number of remaining sublists, including the current sublist being referenced. The result should be as follows.

```
[{'h': '30', 'l': '3'}, {'h': '30', 'l': '3'}, {'h': '25', 'l': '3'}, {'h': '22', 'l': '3'}, {'h': '22', 'l': '3'}]
```

Finding the max and min of the whole list is easy enough, but I cannot figure out the best way to "discard" the preceding subsists and only use the remaining sublists in creating the new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in O(n).

Imagine you want to solve this problem only for max value, (solving it for min value is the same), you just need to iterate from the end of the list to the beginning, while keeping max values with their indices, for your example, this list would be:
[(22,4), (25,2), (30,1)].

Then when you want to answer, you will have a loop starting from 0 to 4, and while your counter is less than or equal to 1, your answer will be 30. After that while your counter is less than or equal to 2, your answer will be 25, and after than while your counter is less than or equal to 4, your answer for max value will be 22.

The same theory applies for finding minimum value.

You can my solution code below:

```
data = [{'h': '20', 'l': '9'}, {'h': '30', 'l': '20'}, {'h': '25', 'l': '7'}, {'h': '18', 'l': '19'}, {'h': '22', 'l': '3'}]

mx_list = []
mx = 0          # Suppose numbers are Natural
mn_list = []    
mn = 1000000    # Suppose it is bigger than all of our numbers

for i, d in enumerate(reversed(data)):
    index = len(data) - i - 1
    print(int(d['h']))
    if int(d['h']) > mx:
         mx_list.append((int(d['h']), index))
         mx = int(d['h'])

for i, d in enumerate(reversed(data)):
    index = len(data) - i - 1
    print(int(d['l']))
    if int(d['l']) < mn:
         mn_list.append((int(d['l']), index))
         mn = int(d['l'])

answer_list = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    if i <= mx_list[len(mx_list)-1][1]:
        cur_mx = mx_list[len(mx_list)-1][0]
    else:
        mx_list.pop()
        cur_mx = mx_list[len(mx_list)-1][0]

    if i <= mn_list[len(mn_list)-1][1]:
        cur_mn = mn_list[len(mn_list)-1][0]
    else:
        mn_list.pop()
        cur_mn = mn_list[len(mn_list)-1][0]
    
    answer_list.append({'h': cur_mx, 'l': cur_mn})

print(answer_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code solves your question:

```
inp = [{'h': '20', 'l': '9'}, {'h': '30', 'l': '20'}, {'h': '25', 'l': '7'}, {'h': '18', 'l': '19'}, {'h': '22', 'l': '3'}]
l1 = inp[::-1]
l2 = []

max1 = int(l1[0]['h'])
min1 = int(l1[0]['l'])
for item in l1:
  max1 = int(item['h']) if int(item['h'])>max1 else max1
  min1 = int(item['l']) if int(item['l'])<min1 else min1
  l2.append({'h':str(max1),'l':str(min1)})

l2 = l2[::-1]
print(l2)
```

### Output

```
[{'h': '30', 'l': '3'}, {'h': '30', 'l': '3'}, {'h': '25', 'l': '3'}, {'h': '22', 'l': '3'}, {'h': '22', 'l': '3'}]
```

### More info

First, I reversed the input list and named it `l1` then I iterate over `l1` holding the current `max1` for `h` and `min1` for `l`. I appended the `max1` and `min1` to `l2` in each iteration. and finally I reversed the `l2` list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for a little help. First you should cast your numbers as ints  as they are strings currently.

```
l = [{'h': '20', 'l': '9'}, {'h': '30', 'l': '20'}, {'h': '25', 'l': '7'}, {'h': '18', 'l': '19'}, {'h': '22', 'l': '3'}]
l = [{k: int(v) for k, v in x.items()} for x in l]
```

Then you can convert them to a dataframe and use `cummax` and `cummin`. You'll have to reverse the order to get it how you describe then reverse that output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l).iloc[::-1]
df['h'] = df['h'].cummax()
df['l'] = df['l'].cummin()
df = df.iloc[::-1]
```

Use `to_dict` to go back to your original format:

```
df.to_dict('records')

[{'h': 30, 'l': 3},
 {'h': 30, 'l': 3},
 {'h': 25, 'l': 3},
 {'h': 22, 'l': 3},
 {'h': 22, 'l': 3}]
```